# How to cast a any-typed Property into a callable in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Given is a return parameter from a function, which is actually a callable, although the functions return type is defined as `any`.

```
const callback = target.getCallback();
```

But when I'd like to execute this callback, I got an error `TS2349: This expression is not callable.`

Example-Code:

```
   callback(true);
```

How can I disable the error of TypeScript or make TypeScript learn that this variable contains a function (which might be the preferable option here)?

Comment: You definitely should not use `any` if you can avoid it. However, I can't seem to reproduce your issue: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCGAnA5gU1gXhgbwFAxjSgGF4AbMgI3mAGsAKASgC4Z4wBPHfAmRdAK6IwMegEsIAMRAhWlGWVTtGMDAD4YoSCEUA6MiGT0A5ADMZxxjwC+uW7i3RN5KjVqq4SIrqKkK1OiYAbgcXAIYoRAFURiA `any` should prevent all typechecking, callables included.

Comment: @AlexWayne turns out, the concrete return value of the getCallback()-Function was indeed a "Ref<any>" (Ref was brought by vue-composition-api) and not a blank "any"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `typeof` check, you can narrow its type down to `function`:

```
const callback = target.getCallback() as unknown;
if (typeof callback === 'function') {
  callback(true);
}
```

If it's *always guaranteed* to be a function, you can:

```
(target.getCallback() as Function)(true);
```

If you aren't permitted to use `Function`, then do something like:

```
(target.getCallback() as (arg: boolean) => unknown)(true);
```

or however the proper type is.

But it would be much better to fix the typing of the `target` object so that this sort of workaround isn't necessary. `getCallback` should be typed properly so that TS can see that it returns a function.

Comment: This will result in another error: "@typescript-eslint/ban-types: Don't use `Function` as a type. The `Function` type accepts any function-like value."